# Webpage doesn't render in ubuntu (tried firefox/chromium/browser) but works in windows

Tags: firefox, internet, chromium, websites

For some reason, I can't view the following webpage:

http://areweb.berkeley.edu/courses/EEP118/current/problemsets/

I asked a windows-using friend, and it works for them.  When I try it, I get the following:

[image]

Anybody know what is causing this and how to fix?

EDIT:  A deleted answer suggested that I "UA Spoofer" (a thing that pretends that I am using a different browser).  Weirdly, this works, but only if I switch browsers every time I load a new page of the main site.  Is this a clue for what is going on?

Comment: Install [Live HTTP Headers](https://addons.mozilla.org/hu/firefox/addon/live-http-headers/) to firefox. Then open it from the *Tools* menu. Load the website. Post the captured HTTP headers here.

Comment: It's a Webpage generated from a MS Word document. I've heard it's one of the worst html-generators in the history of human kind :P

Answer (score 1):

It could be that you're missing the fonts required to display that webpage, usually missing fonts for a webpage are substituted by equivalent ones but looks like this is not possible for that webpage. Depending on your Ubuntu version you should install the package msttcorefonts or ttf-mscorefonts-installer to get the Microsoft fonts.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I have ttf-mscorefonts-installer installed.  Annoyingly, the page is written in comic sans...

Comment: What is the message that you get under the 'X'?

Comment: "Video can't be played because the file is corrupt"

Comment: And you get the same message for all 3 browsers (Firefox/Chromium/Midori)? P.S.: The UA Spoofer thing is even more puzzling, it's not a matter of using Windows anyway, I can see the webpage with Firefox and Chromium on Ubuntu 13.10

Comment: Yes.  The only thing that worked was the UA spoofer in chromium, and even that requires a DIFFERENT spoof browser each time I go to a new page under the overall site.  Its weird!

Comment: Actually, I don't get the same error message, but they all recognize the content as video, which it isn't, and so therefore can't be played.

Answer (score 1):

First install the following:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

And then try again, if you still can´t use the following browser:

http://midori-browser.org/download/ubuntu/

Comment: Thanks, but neither of these worked for me either!